# How to make edit text like this?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, custom-controls

when i clicked the edittext
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw5D8.png)
finally enter mobile number
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElLVl.png)

How to make EditText like this, mobile entering with country code in android?
if anyone know this code please share and thanks in advance for all.

Comment: What have you already tried? If you've tried something, please edit your question to include your code. If not, go try to solve the problem yourself before asking a question on SO, because we won't write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

try this following XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile Number"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+971"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter number"
            android:id="@+id/ed2"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="20sp">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this image is used 2 edit box , one for get first 3 number(Country Code) and another for get other numbers

Comment: how to do the center line and top text "Mobile number" and the underline

Comment: @EbinFrancis for vertical short line take view with width 1dp, height what you need. For horizontal line width  what you need height 1dp

Answer (score 0):

Example for adding Country code 3 digit like +91 or +61

```
  boolean isDeletePressed;

   edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            isDeletePressed = (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
            return false;
        }
    });




 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



            if (editable.toString().length() == 3) {
                if (!isDeletePressed) {
                    edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString() + "|");
                    edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().toString().length());
                }
            } else if (editable.toString().length() == 4) {
                if (!(editable.toString().charAt(3) == '|')) {
                    edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString().substring(0, 3) + "|" + edittext.getText().toString().substring(3));
                    edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().toString().length());
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

[**Youtube Demo**](https://youtu.be/p_jvSUV0igA)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    String Crcode = "+ 971" + "|";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        TextView code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        code.setText(Crcode);

        EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        number.setText(" 2 877 2877");
        number.setSelection(number.getText().length());
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Mobile Number" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+971 | "
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text=" 2 877 2877"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#111111" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not like this man this was type like the i need when i number type the edit text view change like that

Comment: add editext watcher and add your pre fix code in it.